# Liferay 7 JQuery dropdown (+) button

Tags: jquery, css, liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

I wanted to put this navbar [**Here is the Link**](http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/bootstrap-navbar.html) in my Liferay 7 portal theme ( using freemarker ).

The problem is i cant have that (+) in dropdown button in mobile screens.[image]

My navigator console shows :

> Mismatched anonymous define() module: jquery,jquery.smartmenus
>
> Mismatched anonymous define() module: jquery

Here is my code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.smartmenus/1.0.1/addons/bootstrap/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.smartmenus/1.0.1/addons/bootstrap/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.smartmenus/1.0.1/jquery.smartmenus.js"></script>




    <!-- Navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

    <!-- Right nav -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="bootstrap-navbar.html">Default</a></li>
      <li><a href="bootstrap-navbar-static-top.html">Static top</a></li>
      <li><a href="bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top.html">Fixed top</a></li>
      <li><a href="bootstrap-navbar-fixed-bottom.html">Fixed bottom</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
          <li><a href="#">A sub menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a class="disabled" href="#">Disabled item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">A separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Thank You

Comment: hi can you fiddle your code

Comment: Just edit it , thank you for reminding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below code snippet at top of your JSP file

```
<script>
// This is required to load jquery files
// and to overcome the issue : "Mismatched anonymous define() module:" 
define.amd=false;
</script>
```

You can see another solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675161/how-to-add-jquery-uis-datepicker-to-a-liferay-7-portlet/42686056)